# Custom navigation bar background on iOS5

Tags: ios5, navigation

The image I used for background of navigation bar is 640x88. The code for navigation bar is below. It works well for iOS4.3 simulator, but the background image is shown twice as normal on iOS 5 simulator. How can I resize the background image on iOS 5.0?

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)

- (UIImage *)barBackground {
    [self setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f
                                       green: 0.25f
                                        blue:0.09f
                                       alpha:0.6]];
    UIImage *image;
    image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioNav.png"];
    return image; 
}
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    //iOS5 only
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
    {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[self barBackground] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    } 
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[self barBackground] drawInRect:rect]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 images, one for normal resolution display, one for retina display:

- audioNav.png - 320x44
- audioNav@2x.png - 640x88

When using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioNav.png"]` it will always load the correct image.